# Using SCP to copy files from a remote server to external hard drive

Tags: cygwin, scp

I'm having trouble figuring out how to copy a file from a remote server to an external hard drive connected to my local machine. I have cygwin installed in my c drive and I know how to scp files into any directory using:

scp User@remoteserver:/path/to/file.txt /cygdrive/c/path/to/destination

However, I'm not sure how to change the destination to the external hard drive, which I have as the d drive.

Comment: May be `/cygdrive/d/path/to/destination` ?

Comment: That's exactly it, I didn't realize you could simply specify another drive, thought it could only be the one containing cygwin. Thank you!